# Pandas: filling missing values of a dataframe column from a numpy array

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy `array` of size `k`, and a pandas dataframe with a column of size `n>k` that contains `k` missing values.

Is there an easy way to fill the k missing values from the numpy `array` correspondingly (that is, first occurred missing value in the column of the dataframe corresponds to the next value in the array)?

Comment: Can you please provide an example with some sample data values?

Comment: @COLDSPEED Sorry, I am new to stackoverflow, not yet familiar to the interface. Basically, I had a column of ages that contained missing values. I tried to train a classifier to predict the missing ages based on the data from other columns, after which I needed to replace the missing values of that column with the predictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work. You may also want to consider what order (i.e. sorting) you want to fill these values in.

```
fill_values = list(range(k)) #or whatever your array is
indicies_of_missing = df[df['myColumn'].isnull()].index # list of the missing indices
for fill_index, dataframe_index in enumerate(indicies_of_missing):
    dataframe.loc[dataframe_index, 'myColumn'] = fill_values[fill_index]
```